# BigQuery table partitioning difference between legacy and standard sql

Tags: google-bigquery

When a BigQuery table is partitioned using the `--time_partitioning_type=DAY` command line parameter ...

1. Does it create a single physical table or multiple physical tables?Does it differ when using Standard vs Legacy SQL
2. Is the pseudo column _PARTITIONTIME available in both legacy and standard SQL ?
3. Since Standard SQL does not support Partition Decorator , how can one overcome the limitation when using standard SQL ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Does it create a single physical table or multiple physical tables?Does it differ when using Standard vs Legacy SQL

BigQuerys internal system is distributed, so indeed it's multiple physical copies of the same data inside Google's infrastructure. Since it's a managed service, this is transparent for us.

> 2. Is the pseudo column _PARTITIONTIME available in both legacy and standard SQL ?

Yes, it's available. More about where to put this pseduo column in the [examples](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-partitioned-tables).

> 3. Since Standard SQL does not support Partition Decorator , how can one overcome the limitation when using standard SQL ?

Decorators in pure SQL can be mimic with the `_PARTITIONTIME` pseudo column. Think of the decorators as a complementary invention for the API side of this service. When you need to delete a day, and to reload that day into your table, you couldn't do that easily with SQL, but with the API and decorators you are able to run `bq rm 'mydataset.table$20160301'`. Partition decorators enable you to load data into a specific partition: `[TABLE_NAME]$20160301`

Comment: Thanks, I also wanted to know if there are multiple sharded physical tables created in case of  partitioning, or is it a single monolithic tables that is replicated for reliability?

Comment: As Pentium10 said, whether the table is physically sharded is implementation details and should be irrelevant to users. Logically, you can think that the table is sharded. When you query a partitioned table, only the related partitions are read and you're only charged for it. For non-partitioned tables you're always charged for the whole table.

Answer (score 0):

For 3. - decorators are now implemented as in:

```
SELECT *
FROM t
  FOR SYSTEM TIME AS OF '2017-01-01 10:00:00-07:00';
```

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax